# Dynamically search a column up to a static name and extract the address to a new column in Postgres/GIS

Tags: postgresql

I'm totally new to this and just hacking around, but I'm trying to pull out an address that comes before the city name and put it in a new column.  I'm trying to use substring dynamically, but I'm getting lost with the syntax.  Any ideas on where to point me?

Comment: You have a column with data '1212 Main Street, Centerview, Oregon' and you're trying to extract '1212 Main Street' and put that in another column? Please provide more details

Comment: Yes, and the city name is all the same.  I can't do length because the address names are different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be looking at `substr` with regular expression.

Let's say your table as a column 'full_address', with the street, city, and state info. You add a new column simply called street_address, and you want to extract the street address from each row and place it into the street_address column.

First, consider how to get the street address out of the full_address column. Perhaps this regular expression, where break the address into comma separated `<street_address>,<city>,<state>`.

```
(.*),[^,]*,[^,]*
```

Which simply says:

```
capture anything       -- the street address
comma                  -- exact match on a comma
anything not a comma   -- the city, assuming no commas allowed in city
comma                  -- exact match on a second comma
anything not a comma   -- the state.
```

(Clearly, you need to figure out a useful regex for your data).

Given a regex, you can view your street addresses as:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(full_address FROM '(.*),[^,]*,[^,]*') FROM my_table;
```

Assuming the regex captures what you want, you can do an update using:

```
UPDATE my_table SET street_address = SUBSTRING(full_address FROM '(.*),[^,]*,[^,]*');
```